# Angular's KeyValuePipe looses its types

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, angular-pipe

When I'm using the Angular's `KeyValuePipe` in my tempalte, the `key` pipe-results is loosing its type.
Here is an example.

**app.component.ts:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  someObject: Record<`${'key1' | 'key2'}`, {myCustomValue: string}> = 
              {key1: {myCustomValue: 'value1'}, key2:{myCustomValue:'value2'}}

  getKeyValueElement(key: 'key1' | 'key2', value: {myCustomValue: string}){
    console.log(key, value)
  }
}
```

Then in my **app.component.html**:

```
<div *ngFor="let keyValueElement of someObject | keyvalue"
  (click)="getKeyValueElement(keyValueElement.key, keyValueElement.value)">
</div>
```

**And here is the error I get:**

[image]

The app refuses to compile since there is uncompatibility between the `getKeyValueElement` `key` parameter - which is `'key1' | 'key2'`, and the `key` from the pipe-result which is `string`.

Now, there are 2 different ways that I know how to solve it:

1. To use `$any()` in the template to avoid type checking - Not a
   recommended practice.
2. To pass a `compareFn` to the `KeyValuePipe`  with
   the exact requested types in the signature. this will effect the types rendered in the
   `key`&`value` pipe-results. This is also not a good solution in most
   cases when you don't realy need a custom `compareFn`.

So, I'm looking for another solution. In my eyes, this error shold not appeare in the first place.

Comment: Yes, it should appear. The `String` type is way too general, so `keyValueElement.key` which can be *any String whatsoever* is not guaranteed to be `'key1'` or `'key2'`, hence the error.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu But `someObject` has a specific keys-type, Why isn't it guaranteed after passing it through the pipe?

Answer (score 2):

That because of the [signature of `transform`of the keyvalue pipe](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4a05cfdfb2df645d021d1e06553fda036990c6e7/packages/common/src/pipes/keyvalue_pipe.ts#L63).

One of the entries is :
  `transform<K extends number, V>( input: Record<K, V>, compareFn?: (a: KeyValue<string, V>, b: KeyValue<string, V>) => number): Array<KeyValue<string, V>>;`

It matches `type Record<K extends string | number | symbol, T> = { [P in K]: T; }`

You can see `Record` has `number` as key.

So the solution would be to use a proper map :

```
const someObject: Map<('key1' | 'key2'), { myCustomValue: string }> =
    new Map([['key1', { myCustomValue: 'value1' }], ['key2', { myCustomValue: 'value2' }]])
```

Comment: It doesn't help.